# Convert a string into an object with fields

Tags: javascript

suppose we have a string like this:

```
string = 'user - 2021-02-19 08:34:02 - PACKED, user2 - 2021-02-26 12:18:25 - PACKED'
```

How can we convert this string into objects with these fields:

```
if (lastWord == 'PACKED'){
        obj1 = {
                User: 'user',
                Time: '2021-02-19 08:34:02'
        }
        obj2 = {
                User: 'user2',
                Time: '2021-02-26 12:18:25'
        }
}
```

If we use a json.parse the output will be:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(obj):

[
  'user - 2021-02-19 08:34:02 - PACKED',
  'user2 - 2021-02-26 12:18:25 - PACKED'
]
```

I think we can start from here to make things easier.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// input: 'user - 2021-02-19 08:34:02 - PACKED, user2 - 2021-02-26 12:18:25 - PACKED'
// [{ User: 'user', Time: '2021-02-19 08:34:02' }, { User: 'user2', Time: '2021-02-26 12:18:25' }]
function parse(str) {
    const extractPart = str.split(",").map(s => s.trim());
    return extractPart.map(splitEachPart);
}

// input:  user - 2021-02-19 08:34:02 - PACKED
// output: { User: 'user', Time: '2021-02-19 08:34:02' }
function splitEachPart(str) {
    const [user, time, packed] = str.split(" - ")
    return {
        User: user,
        Time: time
    }
}


console.log(parse('user - 2021-02-19 08:34:02 - PACKED, user2 - 2021-02-26 12:18:25 - PACKED'));
```

The code first splits by comma, and then splits by dashes. So we're relying on the assumptions about the commas and the dashes in the input format for the output to be correct.